# Consider the following entities and their relationship

Tags: rdbms

```
Person (p_no, p_name, p_addr)   
Investment (inv_no, inv_name, inv_date, inv_amt)
```

Write a function which will return name of person having maximum total amount of investment.

how to solve the above query using RDBMS

Comment: the problem, of course, is that it's missing the relationship between person and investment

Comment: I have joined the two tables in one to many relation using references while creating table and have written the quesry as follows:

Comment: SQL> select * from p;

      PNO PNAME      ADRS
--------- ---------- ----------
        1 Anil       Pune
        2 Sumit      Pune
        3 Deepak     Ngp

SQL> select * from i;

      INO INAME      IDT            IAMT       PNO
--------- ---------- --------- --------- ---------
      101 Land       24-JUN-14     50000         1
      102 Car        15-OCT-14     20000         1
      103 plot       06-JUN-15     60000         2
      104 house      15-DEC-14     90000         1

Comment: create or replace function f1
return varchar2
as
max_inv_name varchar2(10);
begin
select pname into max_inv_name from p, i
where p.pno=i.pno and i.pno=(select distinct(i.pno) from 
(select distinct(max(sum(iamt))) from i group by i.pno),p);
return max_inv_name;
end;

Comment: I think you should add this info to your question

Comment: If possible kindly provide a solution... Thanks